# Equivalent of HttpContext.IsCustomErrorEnabled is ASP.NET CORE

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a lot of filters, which are using `HttpContext.IsCustomErrorEnabled` in ***MVC 5***. One of such filter is JsonExceptionFilter, to simply return status without full error when exception is fired on Production environment. The details of exception are returned based on CustomeErrors enabled. So in rare cases I can see production/staging error just by chanign this option in web.config. However in ASP.NET Core there is no such option because redirection is done by ExceptionHandler middleware.

Is there any way to check if redirection (custom error) is enabled?

Comment: You can configure the ExceptionHandler by env in your Startup class

Comment: Without restarting the application? Not w/o writing your own middleware. In startup you configure it based on environment setting (production, development, staging) like https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/blob/dev/src/MusicStore/Startup.cs#L97-L111 and this only happens during application startup though